# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process OSX Catalina

Tags: python, macos, selenium, geckodriver, instapy

I install instapy with pip brew install gecodriver
and result is this when I run with sudo
If I run without sudo firefox open instagram page open login details enter and trow me login credentials failed user and pass are correct. Can sombody tell me this is from gecodriver or no And how I can fix it.

```
> InstaPy Version: 0.6.11 .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. Workspace in use:
> "/Users/Ammar/InstaPy" Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "instagrambot .py", line 46, in session =
> InstaPy(username=args.username, password=args.password,
> headless_browser=True) File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/instapy/instapy.py",
> line 321, in init self.browser, err_msg = set_selenium_local_session(
> File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/instapy/browser.py",
> line 126, in set_selenium_local_session browser = webdriver.Firefox(
> File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py",
> line 170, in init RemoteWebDriver.init( File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
> line 157, in init self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
> File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
> line 252, in start_session response =
> self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters) File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
> line 321, in execute self.error_handler.check_response(response) File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
> line 242, in check_response raise exception_class(message, screen,
> stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:
> invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
```

Here is the code

```
from instapy import InstaPy


if args.username and args.password:
    session = InstaPy(username=args.username, password=args.password, headless_browser=False)
    session.login()
elif args.username and args.password and args.proxy and args.port:
    session = InstaPy(username=args.username, password=args.password, proxy_address=args.proxy, proxy_port=args.port, headless_browser=True)
    session.login()


##Quota Supervisior dhourly and day limits

session.set_quota_supervisor(enabled=True, sleep_after=["likes", "comments_d", "follows", "unfollows", "server_calls_h"], sleepyhead=True, stochastic_flow=True, notify_me=True,
                              peak_likes_hourly=45,
                              peak_likes_daily=1000,
                               peak_comments_hourly=21,
                               peak_comments_daily=182,
                                peak_follows_hourly=48,
                                peak_follows_daily=None,
                                 peak_unfollows_hourly=35,
                                 peak_unfollows_daily=402,
                                  peak_server_calls_hourly=None,
                                  peak_server_calls_daily=4700)
```

Comment: do you have code to submit, in addition to the stack trace ?

Comment: edit your post to add your code, and use code formating

Comment: Thats the begining of the script any clue why not runing on osx catalina on ubuntu 18.06 is ok